# how to get all switch cases from the class file into an array

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I need to get all the switch cases from the class file. For example:- "getDeclaredMethods" used to get all methods from the class file, similarly I need to get all switch cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With "getDeclaredMethods" you probably refer to the reflection mechanism. That will not help you with examining the body (implementation) of the methods.
You would need to use some source code analyser, assuming you have access to the source code.
The same maybe is possible even with the byte code.